Git Hub - parallel-test execution junit
I am trying to configure a GitHub workflow to run the tests in parallel using the modified split-tests output.
The gradle command what each parallel runner requires to execute looks like:
./gradlew test  --tests "org.parallel.big.BigExecution2Test" --tests "org.parallel.big.BigExecution7Test" --tests "org.parallel.huge.HugeExecution4Test" --tests "org.parallel.huge.HugeExecutionTest" --tests "org.parallel.medium.MediumExecution6Test" --tests "org.parallel.small.SmallExecution3Test" --tests "org.parallel.small.SmallExecution8Test" --warning-mode all
However, it seems that I might be passing the wrong configuration to the gradlew test command. It says the command is not correct and no tests were found:
Execution failed for task ':core:test'.

No tests found for given includes: * ["org.parallel.big.BigExecution2Test", "org.parallel.huge.HugeExecutionTest", "org.parallel.medium.MediumExecution6Test", "org.parallel.small.SmallExecution3Test", "org.parallel.huge.HugeExecution4Test", "org.parallel.small.SmallExecution8Test", "org.parallel.big.BigExecution7Test"](--tests filter)

Does anyone have any insights into what could be causing the issue?
The test repo where I want to setup this can be find here
